# What is a better way of writing this oracle sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Somehow, this does not seem very efficient.. Can this be optimized of made more efficient?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.col1 from table1 p where p.col1 not in
(SELECT DISTINCT o.col1 from table1 o where o.col2 = 'ABC')
```

For ex, select all supermarkets that do not have product = soap

Comment: how about --select distinct col1 from table1 where col1 <> 'ABC'-- ?

Comment: select distinct o.col2 from table1 o where o.col1 in (select distinct p.col1 from table1 p where p.col2 <> 'ABC') still gives rows with the value ABC

Comment: true, sorry, let me fix the col :-) anyway, there's already an answer like that

Answer (score 3):

You want all `col1` values where `col2` is never `'ABC'`.  You can approach this with aggregation:

```
select p.col1
from table1 p
group by p.col1
having sum(case when p.col2 = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Why is this faster?  Well, there are cases where it won't be.  But it often will be.  A `select distinct` is doing an aggregation anyway.  So, other methods that use join's or in are adding extra work.  Now, this extra work is worth it if they significantly reduce the amount of data being processed.

Also, `not in` is dangerous semantically.  If any values of `col1` are `NULL` whenever `col2 = 'ABC'`, then all data will be filtered out.  That is, the query will return no rows at all.  That can be sped up a great deal!  This formulation assumes that `col1` is never `NULL` in this case.

Finally, if you have a list of `col1` values that is already unique, then the fastest method is probably:

```
select c.col1
from col1table c
where not exists (select 1 from table1 o where o.col1 = c.col1 and o.col2 = 'ABC')
```

For this query, an index on `table1(col1, col2)` is optimal for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just querying with a not clause?

i.e.
select distinct col1 from table1 where col2 <> 'ABC'

Comment: this makes more sense to me too

Comment: what are p and o in this query?

Comment: @DavidAldridge thanks for pointing that out. I removed the variable references since both tables he is querying from are the same.

Comment: select distinct o.col2 from table1 o where o.col1 in (select distinct p.col1 from table1 p where p.col2 <> 'ABC') still gives rows with the value ABC

Comment: @JavaGWTDeveloper did you try after my update, with no variable reference (no 'o' or 'p')

Comment: This would be "select all supermarkets which stock any product other than soap", I think?

Comment: @DavidAldridge pretty much. Depending on what col1 and col2 actually represent. Not sure which is the 'supermarket' and which is the 'product'.

I kept it as a single query since its on the same table and we are not searching for a min/max or anything like that .

Comment: This is not equivalent to the original query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will review this further later today. If I see it has no use I will update it or delete. Thanks for the note

Answer (score 1):

I would structure that along the lines of:

```
select supermarkets.*
from   supermarkets
where  not exists (
         select 1
         from   product_in_supermarkets
         where  product_in_supermarkets.supermarket_id = supermarkets.id and
                product_in_supermarkets.product_type = 'soap')
```

Have an index on:

```
product_in_supermarkets(supermarket_id, product_type)
```

for best performance.

Now having said that, it could be that under the right circumstances a NOT EXISTS and a NOT IN query get transformed to be the same, and an anti-join would be executed. Semantically I like the correlated subquery with not exists, as I think it better represents the intent of the query.

NOT IN is also susceptible to unexpected effects should there be a null value in the projection from the subquery, as no value can be said to be not in a list that includes NULL (including NULL).

Comment: See additional notes above

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider creating an index on `col1`.

I'd also try using

```
select distinct p.col1 from table1 p where not exists
(select distinct o.col1 from table1 o where o.col1 = p.col1 and o.col2 = 'ABC');
```

Also, depending on the amount of rows and data entropy, sometimes avoiding the distinct from the inner query can be an useful trade-off.

Comment: The distinct is logically redundant in this correlated subquery. I'd expect the query optimiser to remove it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you just answered some 30 seconds earlier. :)